# what is this operator called and what is it used for <=>

Tags: grails, groovy, operators

I recently came across this magical operator when digging into Groovy: <=>

Groovy has really made me happy with elvis operators ?. and ?: which I use constantly now and very much wish were in Java.  With this new operator, I have only found this [reference](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).  It seems to make comparators much easier.  My question is how does it handle null values and how does it compare non Comparable object.  Does this operator have a name, I couldn't find it Googling.

Comment: This is not a Java question ... removing bogus tag.

Comment: @Stephen no problem, I tagged as java since groovy is superset.  Wasn't sure if there might have been something in java I had missed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got [a list of operators here](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html). It is called the "Spaceship" operator. It [handles null without problem](http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/02/08/the-groovy-spaceship-operator-explained/).

Answer (score 5):

It's called the spaceship operator and is also commonly used for comparison in Ruby.

http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/02/08/the-groovy-spaceship-operator-explained/

Answer (score 2):

Name : **Spaceship operator**

Method that it uses : **a.compareTo(b)** //where a and b are the variables that has been used

Class : **java.lang.Comparable**

And this link explains about that operator in a bit more . Click [Here](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2007/04/03/the-groovy-spaceship-operator.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like many others mention, it's called the spaceship operator. Here's my test:

```
def a
def b

println 1 <=> 0                 // 1
println 0 <=> 1                 // -1
println 1 <=> a                 // 1
println b <=> 0                 // -1
println a <=> b                 // 0
println "abc" <=> "def"         // -1
println "abc" <=> 1             // throw exception: java.lang.ClassCastException
```