# What is the "<=>" operator for?

Tags: sorting, groovy, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is this operator called and what is it used for <=>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321745/what-is-this-operator-called-and-what-is-it-used-for)

I have been curious about the type and working of this kind of operator "<=>"?

Basically, I was struggling to sort my collections in groovy. Due to some reason all the java and groovy collections sort functions were failed to produce the desired result. By doing some googling I found the sort closure which worked for me, closure code is pasted below:

```
blahblah.findAll{it -> (it.blahblah == "blahblah" || it.blahblah2 == "blahblah") && (it.blahblah == blahblah)}.sort{a,b -> a.id <=> b.id}*.blah()
```

Can anyone clarify me about what type of operator is this and how it worked at the behind to complete the job?